# handle custom service worker response

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to return a custom response from service worker. When fetching request from network while not available check from cache if also failed I want to return a custom `html` response or `image` depending on the request url type.

I have below code but it doesn't work, please provide any idea how I can get this working or better solution for my sw.

[Here is my full SW script](https://jsfiddle.net/1876y3sp/)

**Sample Code**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    var cacheType = (function () {
        if (is('image', event.request.url)) {
            return cacheImage;
        } else if (is('html', event.request.url)) {
            return cacheHtml;
        } else if (event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/css') || event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('*/*')) {
            return cacheFiles;
        } else {
            return cacheFiles;
        }
    })();

    // Jump to offline page when there is no network
    if (!self.navigator.onLine) {
        //console.log('[ServiceWorker] No network, jump offline page');
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                return caches.match(offlineUrl);
            })
        );
    } else {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.open(cacheType).then(function (cache) {
                return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        // console.log('[ServiceWorker]Take in the cache %s', event.request.url);
                        if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && event.request.mode !== 'same-origin') return;

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
                                if(isValidResponse(response, event.request.url)) {
                                    caches .open(cacheType) .then(function (cache) {
                                        if(event.request.method == "GET" && (response.status === 200 || response.status === 0)){
                                            cache.put(event.request, response);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }, 2000);
                        return response || unableToResolve();
                    }

                    if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && event.request.mode !== 'same-origin') return;

                    return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                        if(event.request.method == "GET" && (response.status === 200 || response.status === 0)){
                            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                        }
                         return response ||  unableToResolve();
                    }).catch(function(err){
                         return unableToResolve();
                    });
                });

                function unableToResolve () {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] fetch request failed in both cache and network');
                    return new Response('<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>', {
                        status: 503,
                        statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
                        headers: new Headers({
                          'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                        })
                    });
                }

            })
        );
    }
});
```

I have been trying with no better attempt.

Comment: What specific thing is not working for you? It would be good if you could add to the question the exact scenario (online or offline; cache present or not present) and what do you expect it to do.

Comment: @vatz88 what i want is, when offline and request url is not in cache return a custom html from `unableToResolve `